# exceptions import SSLError, InsecurePlatformWarning when using pip, python3.4 win32

Tags: python, pip

I installed Python 3.4.0, but I can't use pip. So then I installed pip from python.org. Then I set PATH.
when I use pip, it reports these:

```
  C:\Users\think\Downloads\pip-7.1.2>pip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 171, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
     ...
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\conn
ectionpool.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\conn
ection.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .util import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util
\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util
\ssl_.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..exceptions import SSLError, InsecurePlatformWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'InsecurePlatformWarning'
```

Python3.4.0 on Win32

Comment: You downloaded the windows version from https://www.python.org/downloads/ ? PIP should in included.

Answer (score 0):

Please assure that you are running pip module that was intalled in the include path of your python version.

You can do this via `python -m pip install <somemodule>`. If this fails you probably do not have the right module.

Also, you may want to install the modules for current user only, by using `python -m pip install --user <somemodule>`